# Mate Desktop - Show/Hide application windows at the bottom

Tags: ubuntu, mate

I am using Ubuntu with Mate, and I have been looking through all the look and feel options (at least I think that) and I don't find where is the option to:

Hide / Show the applications at the bottom. I have another machine where I have lost it and don't know where to set it again.

I show a picture highlighting what I refer to:

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is the window-list applet. You can add it by a right-click on the panel and then selecting "add to panel". There you search for window-list click on "add" and you're done.